# making a xamarin forms app(ios and android) with node js/firebase backend and cant figure out how to attach clientside to backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, xamarin.forms, frontend, backend

Summary
I am creating a node js backend to my Xamarin forms app and am using firebase database to store data. currently I can use node js to save strings to the firebase data base and also could use c# to save information directly from client-side code but to be more secure I have decided to have firebase code run on node js. and am not sure how to connect Xamarin forms code to node js securely. (using crypto). I have the current node js code below.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
   databaseURL: 'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/'
 });

 let db = admin.firestore();

 let docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

 let setAda = docRef.set({
 first: 'Ada',
 last: 'Lovelace',
 born: 1815
  });
```

so my question is how to I have my Xamarin form client side code send strings and save them with this code. in the future I will be using access tokens but not as of yet.

my current c# code has no attachment to the database but I will add anyway(register page and will use firebase authentication)

```
 namespace Kula
 {
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
     public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
    // set variables 
    string email;
    string password;
    Entry RinputEmail;
    Entry RinputPassword;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // reference mainpage.xamal
        RinputEmail = this.FindByName<Entry>("Remail");
        RinputPassword = this.FindByName<Entry>("Rpassword");

    }

    async private void GTLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //navigate to Login page
        await Navigation.PushAsync (new Login());
    }

    private void registerUser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set users input to strings
        email = (RinputEmail.Text).ToString();
        password = (RinputPassword.Text).ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: use HttpClient to make requests to your backend.  Use https for secure communication

Comment: do you have sample code on how to retrieve it in node js. and also do I use the local server as the Url link? and could someone just paste that url into there browser(when I deploy) and see users private info? also is http just another form of sha- 256 keys im completely new to encryption and don't understand it much yet @Jason

Comment: there are probably hundreds or thousands of existing samples of using HttpClient with a node server.  You should also research existing authentication mechanisms for node servers